# How to connect Bitbucket to Jenkins properly

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket

Since about 1 week now, Bitbucket doesn't (?) send a request to my Jenkins server.

I've set it all up like this:

`Endpoint` `http://username:apitoken@jenkinshost/`
`username` = username in Jenkins
`apitoken` = apitoken connected to the username in Jenkins
`jenkinshost` = my host where I run Jenkins

`Project  name` is a project
`Token`: The token I can setup in the per-project configuration.

I've done this according to this website: [`http://felixleong.com/blog/2012/02/hooking-bitbucket-up-with-jenkins`](http://felixleong.com/blog/2012/02/hooking-bitbucket-up-with-jenkins).
It did work, but it doesn't anymore. Did Bitbucket change something? How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: @andrewdotnich About everything that is possible. At the end Ive done it like robjohncox says (below), with checking for differences. It works, but I don't like the polling part. I just want instant rebuild when I commit...

Comment: Can you add more detail about *how* it doesn't work? What error messages are you getting (if any?) Is there anything in the Jenkins logs?

Comment: It worked, and from a certain time it din't work anymore. I DONT get error messages as this request should happen *from* the Bitbucket host, *to* my server. [sarcasm] Unfortunately I've no root access to the Bitbucket application [/sarcasm]. I might misunderstand your question, if so, please enlighten me :)
Also: when I try to do the request myself, by pointing a web browser to my endpoint, it does work. Which means in my understanding, Bitbucket is doing something wrong, or doing nothing at all.

Comment: You may try out the Bitbucket OAuth Plugin to connect Bitbucket and Jenkins. You can find steps [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+OAuth+Plugin)

Comment: Does this have anything to do with pulling from the remote repository (Bitbucket)?

Comment: I can trigger a build by hitting a URL in Jenkins, but BitBucket doesn't seem to be sending the right request.

Comment: @Deejay same thing what I saw.

Comment: @Deejay, how you will trigger a build by hitting a URL in Jnekins?

Comment: @Highmastdon, did you manage to make it working?

Comment: @securecurve haven't had time or need to fix it. However, I will look into it very soon because the server where it runs, will be reinstalled. I'll report back my findings.

Comment: @Highmastdon, Thanks for your response .. I got it working. Check my answer below

Answer (score 31):

In order to build your repo after new commits, use [Bitbucket Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Plugin).

**There is just one thing to notice:
When creating a POST Hook (notice that it is POST hook, not Jenkins hook), the URL works when it has a "/" in the end. Like:**

```
URL: JENKINS_URL/bitbucket-hook/
e.g. someAddress:8080/bitbucket-hook/
```

Do not forget to check "Build when a change is pushed to Bitbucket" in your job configuration.

Comment: The trailing "/" is what got it working for me. PHEW! Thanks!

Comment: For me this does not work - I get a `403` error back here. :/

Comment: @mark maybe this link can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427557/jenkins-and-github-webhook-http-403

Comment: Yes, it seems that the Webhooks feature in Bitbucket works perfectly with the Jenkins plugin, just need to add the trailing slash in the end. Tested when using Jenkins with Google based authentication (OAUTH). Thanks!

Comment: missing "/" was the exact issue. Thanks.

Comment: how can you get the exact URL to give to bitbucket?

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar problems, till I got it working. Below is the full listing of the integration:

1. Generate public/private keys pair: `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
2. Copy the public key (~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) and paste it in Bitbucket SSH keys, in user’s account management console:
   [image]
3. Copy the private key (~/.ssh/id_rsa) to new user (or even existing one) with private key credentials, in this case, username will not make a difference, so username can be anything:
   [image]
4. run this command to test if you can get access to Bitbucket account:
   `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org`
5. OPTIONAL: Now, you can use your git to to copy repo to your desk without passwjord `git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/repo_name.git`
6. Now you can enable Bitbucket hooks for Jenkins push notifications and automatic builds, you will do that in 2 steps:

   1. Add an authentication token inside the job/project you configure, it can be anything:
      [image]
   2. In Bitbucket hooks: choose jenkins hooks, and fill the fields as below:
      [image]

Where:

```
**End point**: username:usertoken@jenkins_domain_or_ip
**Project name**: is the name of job you created on Jenkins
**Token**: Is the authorization token you added in the above steps in your Jenkins' job/project 

Recommendation: I usually add the usertoken as the authorization Token (in both Jenkins Auth Token job configuration and Bitbucket hooks), making them one variable to ease things on myself.
```

Comment: For some reason, jenkins can't connect to the repo (permissions denied) but if I try to ssh to bitbuck from the jenkins box, bitbucket takes the key just fine :(

Answer (score 14):

I was just able to successfully trigger builds on commit using the Hooks option in Bitbucket to a Jenkins instance with the following steps (similar as link):

1. Generate a custom UUID or string sequence, save for later
2. Jenkins -> Configure Project -> Build Triggers -> "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)"
3. (Paste UUID/string Here) for "Authentication Token"
4. Save
5. Edit Bitbucket repository settings
6. Hooks -> Edit:
   Endpoint: http://jenkins.something.co:9009/
   Module Name:
   Project Name: Project Name
   Token: (Paste UUID/string Here)

The endpoint did not require inserting the basic HTTP auth in the URL despite using authentication, I did not use the Module Name field and the Project Name was entered case sensitive including a space in my test case.  The build did not always trigger immediately but relatively fast.  One other thing you may consider is disabling the "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" option in "Configure Global Security" for testing as I've experienced all sorts of API difficulties from existing integrations when this option was enabled.

Comment: Great! I've seen a change in how BitBucket calls their 'services'. A rename into hooks indeed. So maybe they've been fixing things regarding this. I'll have a look and if it's working I'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

By iterating I learned that the Token field and the token in an endpoint can be the same. So I set them to be the same as the user token and it works! Also check that the user has privileges to make a job.

Anyway, you can check *access.log* and see if Bitbucket makes a try or not.

[image: jenkins]

P.S. Also a link to [Bitbucket Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Jenkins+hook+management). May some day it will become more useful.

Comment: The link doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with this plugin, but we quite successfully use Bitbucket and Jenkins together, however we poll for changes instead of having them pushed from BitBucket (due to the fact our build server is hidden behind a company firewall). This approach may work for you if you are still having problems with the current approach.

This document on [Setting up SSH for Git & Mercurial on Linux](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678) covers the details of what you need to do to be able to communicate between your build server and Bitbucket over SSH. Once this is done, with the [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) installed, go to your build configuration and select 'Git' under Source Code Management, and enter the ssh URL of your repository as the repository URL. Finally, in the Build Triggers section, select Poll SCM and set the poll frequency to whatever you require.

Comment: Yes I know this solution, but I'm explicitly looking for setting up this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it turned out the issue was that I had named my repository with CamelCase. Bitbucket automatically changes the URL of your repository to be all lower case and that gets sent to Jenkins in the webhook. Jenkins then searches for projects with a matching repository. If you, like me, have CamelCase in your repository URL in your project configuration you will be able to check out code, but the pattern matching on the webhook request will fail.

Just change your repo URL to be all lower case instead of CamelCase and the pattern match should find your project.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I have successfully established the connection between Jenkins and Bitbucket server but I'm having issues getting into the directory on the ec2 server where I have cloned my bitbucket repo>

Below is my script and Jenkins Console output

```
pipeline {
agent any

stages {
    stage('Checkout Git Repository') {
        steps {
            // Set up the checkout directory
            sh 'cd /var/lib/jenkins/test'
            sh 'git status'
            sh 'ls -la /var/lib/jenkins'

            // Check out the current branch of the Git repository
            dir('/home/ec2-user/Sona-Grafana/BitBucket-Repo/observability/soc-poc') {
                git url: 'https://Emmanuel-Sona@bitbucket.org/emmanuel-sona/soc-jenkins.git'
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

I cannot cd into /home/ec2-user/Sona-Grafana/BitBucket-Repo/observability/soc-poc. It only allows me entry into /var/lib/jenkins/test

Docker-compose file used in spinning up the Jenkins server that runs on the EC2 instance

```
version: '3'

services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: ops_jenkins_server
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /opt/jenkins_container_volume:/var 
      - /home/ec2-user/Sonalake-Grafana/BitBucket-Repo/observability/soc-poc:/var/lib/jenkins  
    environment:
      - JENKINS_OPTS="--httpPort=8080"
      - JAVA_OPTS="-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"

  docker:
    image: docker:latest
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

volumes:
  jenkins_home:

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```