# How can I make Jenkins only build feature branches if they have changed when triggering from bitbucket

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, branch, bitbucket

I have a Jenkins job that builds branches that match "origin/feature/**".

Bitbucket triggers the job to build whenever there are changes to the repository via a repository hook (https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Jenkins+hook+management).

This works fine whenever there is a change on a feature branch, the job recognizes that the branch has changed and builds it.

However, when there is a commit to a non-feature branch (eg. a merge to develop or master) bitbucket still triggers the job. There are no changes to any of the feature branches so it just builds the last built feature branch again.

Is there a way to control this?

Comment: Need more context. Is Bitbucket calling the jenkins API of your job to start the build? Parameterized trigger? SCM Polling?

Comment: Bitbucket is calling jenkins using a repository hook. I have updated the question with the details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some research I found a good solution finally:

- Install [Bitbucket Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin) at your Jenkins
- Add a normal Post as Hook to your Bitbucket repository (*Settings -> Hooks*) and use following url:

> https://*YOUR.JENKINS.SERVER:PORT*/bitbucket-hook/

- Configure your Jenkins project as follows:

  - under **build trigger** enable **Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket**
  - under **Source Code Management** select **GIT**; enter your credentials and define **Branches to build** (like ***feature/**)

By this way I have three build projects, one for all features, one for develop and one for release branch.

Comment: Just a comment about the URL: URL should be like this: URL: JENKINS_URL/bitbucket-hook/ having the "/" in the end!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507895/how-to-connect-bitbucket-to-jenkins-properly/29526522#29526522

Comment: "bitbucket_hook" stands for job's name?

Comment: actually not, it's a string part of the URL. You might want to checkout Jenkins Pipeline to see if that match your case. (It happened a lot since these days ;) )

Comment: you are correct but I want to do in jenkins pipeline job .

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the comments section you linked to. Bitbucket will always call the hook to your job.

You need a proxy in front of Jenkins to segregate out posts.

https://github.com/oveddan/gitBuildForwarder

If this was SVN, I would tell you how to alter the SVN hook to only selectively trigger the hook based on Regex filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Since i can not answer the comment top (whyever)

*"you are correct but I want to do in jenkins pipeline job"*

To let a pipeline-job build automatically after a push (per hook) i created another job that is configured just to be triggered by the bitbucket/git and has a follow-up job that points to the pipeline-job in the post-build-action. That was the only way i could manage this

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/).

- Resolve the branch name, from the JSON payload, into a variable like `reference`.
- The optional filter text can be set to `$reference` and the filter regexp set to `^(refs/heads/feature/.+)$`