# How do I programmatically upload a file to a github repo's Downloads area?

Tags: git, ant, github

I have an ANT build which creates files (zip, jar, etc). I wish to push these files to my github repo's "Downloads" area, either via Tasks available to me with ANT (I've tried scp to no avail), via Jenkins (I've tried "Publish over SSH", to no avail) or some other means.

Thanks for guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That means using the **[GitHub V3 API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/downloads/)** in order to:

- [create a download entry](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/downloads/#create-a-new-download-part-1-create-the-resource) on your GitHub repo download page
- [upload the file to S3](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/downloads/#create-a-new-download-part-2-upload-file-to-s3)

See those ruby scripts as a practical example of how this API is used:
"[`lib/octokit/client/downloads.rb`](https://github.com/pengwynn/octokit/pull/97/files)".

If you need to do it from ant though, you could consider the [HTTP-Post task of ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/post_task.html).
Or have your ant script calls commands like "[HTTPie: cURL for Humans](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie/)"
Or use directly Jenkins, as in "[Connect Github to secured Jenkins via HTTP Post-Commit Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957219/connect-github-to-secured-jenkins-via-http-post-commit-hook)"

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom step where you script curl.